# Auto Rounding SQL d

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have a database on mySQL, with course and prices(DECIMAL 10.0). The problem is when I add a price, eg 12.5, sql converts to 13.
Why this is happened?

Comment: `DECIMAL 10.0` => no fractional digits => rounding

Answer (score 1):

To define a column whose data type is DECIMAL you use the following syntax:

```
column_name DECIMAL(P, D)
```

Where P is the precision that represents the number of digits to the left of the decimal, & D is the scale that represents the number of digits to the right of the decimal

Hence, in your example `prices(DECIMAL 10.0)`

P is 10 and D is 0.

Therefore, in your column prices, there will always be 10 digits to the left of the decimal, and 0 to the right of the decimal.

To update the prices column to allow more digits to the right of the decimal, the syntax is as follows:

```
alter table table_name modify column prices DECIMAL(10,4);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I change my table to DECIMAL(5,2)